# Connecting via ssh to remote and go to same directory as used on client

Tags: server, ssh, directory

I have a very specific question. Is it somehow possible to connect from my client via ssh to a remote machine and stay on the same directory I used on the client?

For example if I am in the folder `/path/to/folder/` I want to login to the remote machine and go directly to the same folder. If I logout from the remote, go to another folder, let's say `/path/to/folder/test/`, and log in again via ssh I want to connect to my remote machine and go to this other folder.

Currently I have in my `config` file the following which works fine but only for ONE specific folder:

```
Host test
    Hostname test-server
    User user
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    RemoteCommand cd /path/to/folder && exec bash --login
    RequestTTY yes
```

I tried to change `cd /path/to/folder/` to `cd ${PWD}` but that only directs to my home folder and not the path I was working in on the client. Is there any chance to implement the behavior I want?
I am grateful for any kind of help. If you need any additional information just let me know.

Many thanks, Daniel